# Problem in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like this 
**table1**

```
Unix     |    Staffid
_____________________
534      |     65
342      |     34
232      |     232
232      |     34
```

**table2**

```
Staffid   |    auth
____________________
65        |  y
34        |  y
78        |  n
45        |  y
```

LIke this..
I have to select those staffid having auth y And which is not at this particular unix.. for example at particular unix 232 I can select 65 but not 34...I need for all unix values.

Comment: HTML table? (because th title is jquery) or Database table? (mysql tag)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a slightly different interpretation of the question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Unix, t2.Staffid
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.auth = 'Y'
    AND t2.Staffid NOT IN (select Staffid FROM table1 WHERE Unix = t1.Unix)
    ORDER BY t1.Unix;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Staffid
FROM table2 AS t2
WHERE auth = 'y'
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM table1 AS t1
        WHERE t1.Staffid = t2.Staffid
          AND t1.Unix = 232
      )
```